# Changing build type to Release causes "Cannot resolve symbol" for some classes

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, proguard, android-build-type

When I change my build type to release, some of my class are being shown as "Cannot find symbol" in the android studio. Even though the error is being shown, the application is successfully built and run. When I change back to debug these files are recognized properly.

This is my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'realm-android'

apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'


android {
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            keyAlias 'debugkey-name'
            keyPassword 'dpassword'
            storeFile file('debugkey.jks')
            storePassword 'dspassword'
        }
        release {
            keyAlias 'releasekey-name'
            keyPassword 'rpassword'
            storeFile file('releasekey.jks')
            storePassword 'rspassword'
        }
    }

compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.app.appname"
    minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
    targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
    multiDexEnabled true
    versionCode 0
    versionName "0.9.2"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

applicationVariants.all { variant ->

    variant.outputs.all {
        outputFileName = "Appname-${variant.name}-${defaultConfig.versionName}.apk"
    }

}

buildTypes {

    debug {
        minifyEnabled false
        shrinkResources false
        resValue "string", "map_box_key", "mapboxfakeKeyalksdk;lk;laksd;lkas;ldkndasdjasndkaklsjdlaksdjlaksjdkajsdlkj"
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        debuggable true
        jniDebuggable true
    }

    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        resValue "string", "map_box_key", "mapboxkeyfakekajsdhkajdsklajlskdjlaksjdajlskjdlkjaslkdjlkasjdlkajdlkjaslkd"
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        debuggable false
        jniDebuggable false
        renderscriptDebuggable false
    }
}

flavorDimensions "Environment"

productFlavors {

    appDemo {
        resValue "string", "app_name", "AppName"
        resValue "string", "url_base_address", "https://baseurl.com"
        dimension "Environment"
    }

    appDev {
        applicationIdSuffix ".dev"
        resValue "string", "app_name", "Dev-AppName"
        resValue "string", "url_base_address", "https://baseurl.com"
        dimension "Environment"
    }

}

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

lintOptions {
    disable 'LogNotTimber'
}

}

android.sourceSets {

test {
    java.srcDirs = ["src/main/java", "src/mock/java", "src/test/java"]
}

androidTest {
    java.srcDirs = ["src/main/java", "src/mock/java", "src/androidTest/java"]
}

appDemo {
    java.srcDirs = ["src/main/java", "src/real/java"]
}

appDev {
    java.srcDirs = ["src/main/java", "src/real/java"]
}
}

dependencies {
    //so many dependencies
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

This is my proguard rules:

```
-keepclassmembers class 
android.support.design.internal.BottomNavigationMenuView {
    boolean mShiftingMode;
}
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
-keep class com.crashlytics.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.crashlytics.**

-keep class android.support.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.** { *; }
```

When I try to manually import some file I am not able to see some packages and  classes but I am able to go to them with search option in android studio(double shift)
[image]

**Things I have tried:**

1. Clean and rebuild the project
2. Invalidate cache and restart
3. Deleted .idea and .gradle folders and rebuild
4. Synced the project
5. update build tools

When I go back to debug, the issue is not there, so it seems like the issue is with my Gradle config.

Please help me find the issue.

Comment: share the exact error.

Comment: @RanjanKumar This is the exact error..when I switch to a different buildtype, some classes are not getting detected by android studio. But I am able to build and run the app.

Comment: did u find the fix? having same issue... and yeah i can run the app though...

Comment: @USMANosman Not yet.. Upvote the question so it reaches more people

Answer (score -1):

For testing purpose modify you app build.gradle to not to optimize apk for release build.

```
release {
        minifyEnabled false
        shrinkResources false

....
..}
```

Comment: Its not proguard. I tried that. the issue is still there. btw the downvote is not mine