# Does someone know how to fix unrecognized (red) classes when switching flavours in android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

i hvae an app with two flavours and whenever I startup Android Studio Arctic Fox (and also earlier) it recognizes all the classes from the current flavour correctly. However, when switching to a different Flavour build the classes that have an alternative version in the new flavour are not recognized by the IDE and appear in red.

Now I know this can be fixed by simply rebooting android studio, or alternatively going to `File > Invalidate caches/restart` (Which takes just as long as rebooting) so I sak myself if there is a way to get android studio to doo this faster or at least with less steps. I remember this actually used to work in Android Studio 3.something.

I ask because I find myself switching between flavours quite often and its a bit anoying to always get this wrong error messages in my code.

Comment: I never saw this behavior. I'm using flavors, and whiching between them, without restart the IDE or do a Cache Invalidation. Did you try to reinstall Android Studio?

Comment: yes, ive been haing this behaviour since at least Android Studio 4.1. you also have a windows machine?

Comment: Sure, I'm using Studio on Windows 10 and now on Windows 11 without this specific issue. Try asking in official Android Studio BugTracker site.

Comment: good idea. I know Im not the only one with the issue as I have seen similar questions on SO and thats where I have the invalidate caches fix from.

Comment: look at this post and associated comments https://stackoverflow.com/q/55183515/10637400